# How can I shorten a file from the command line?

Tags: bash, unix, file-management

I have a 150GB xml file that I would like to shorten (ie truncate) to about 1GB - is there a simple (bash or similar) command I can use, or do I have to go the programmatic route (editing it in vi or emacs is a nightmare even on big iron systems)?

(I am not particlarly concerned about the loss of information, I want a shorter file so I can test a piece of software on this and not wait many hours for the answer, a shorter file will allow me to do that.)

Comment: Do you mean you want to truncate the file, or do you want to remove information from throughout the file?

Comment: Found this on SO; https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934078/2800918.

Comment: Good point AFH, I mean truncate and will edit to make that clear

Comment: Another tool for slicing and dicing the content would be [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).

Comment: Since this is an XML file, which I assume contains a sequence with a great number of elements, you could also use an XML transformation language such as XQuery to filter out a certain number of these elements, which would have the advantage to output valid XML ([Example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/f9841b8d72bc7cb21b7c1d721c2995cb))

Comment: Does the file still need to be valid XML when done?

Comment: no, I just patched it up so it was

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you want to truncate and extract the first 1 GB of the 150 GB file:

With `head`:

`head -c 1G infile > outfile`

Note that the `G` suffix can be replaced with `GB` to align to 1000 instead of 1024.

Or with `dd`:

`dd if=infile of=outfile bs=1M count=1024`

Or as in Wumpus Q. Wumbley's answer, `dd` can truncate in place.

Comment: That will likely not result in a readable XML file when done.

Comment: @Joe - OP did not request a readable file (nor did they say it could be unreadable). They did say that they did not care about loss of information.  I would expect a new question from OP about how to fix said file.

Comment: I know enough xml to fix it, I wrote the DTD for the format!

Answer (score 37):

To truncate a file to 1 gigabyte, use the `truncate` command:

```
truncate -s 1G file.xml
```

The result of truncation will likely not be a valid XML file but I gather that you understand that.

Documentation for the GNU version of `truncate` is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/truncate-invocation.html) and documentation for the BSD version is [here](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/truncate/)

Answer (score 14):

Where possible, I'd use the `truncate` command as in John1024's answer. It's not a standard unix command, though, so you might some day find yourself unable to use it. In that case, `dd` can do an in-place truncation too.

`dd`'s default behavior is to truncate the output file at the point where the copying ends, so you just give it a 0-length input file and tell it to start writing at the desired truncation point:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=filename bs=1048576 seek=1024
```

(This is not the same as the copy-and-truncate `dd` in multithr3at3d's answer.)

Note that I used 1048576 and 1024 because 1048576*1024 is the desired size. I avoided bs=1m because this is a "portability" answer, and classic `dd` only knows suffixes `k`, `b`, and `w`.

Comment: For the general solution, you should probably note that the `bs` number multiplied by the `seek` number is the number of bytes to keep.  Any two numbers that satisfy that constraint should work; e.g., ``bs=1073741824 seek=1`` or ``bs=1 seek=1073741824``.  Or, since `bs` defaults to 512, `seek=2097152` alone should also work.  And you can use notation like `1M`, `1K`, `1G` and `2M`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Do you just want to get rid of the other 149GB or are you trying to compress 150GB into 1 GB?  Regardless, this may be a useful method to accomplish this.

The `split` command can split any file into multiple pieces. See [man split](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split).  You can specify the size of the file chunks you want to split it into with the `-b` option.  For instance:

$ split -b 1GB myfile.xml

Without any other options this should create several files in the current directory starting with the letter `x`.  If you want to adjust the names of the split files refer to the man page.

To re-assemble the file just use `cat * > re-assembled.xml`.

Example:

```
[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ ls -l opendocman*
-rw-rw-r--.  1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py 2082602 Mar 31  2017 opendocman-1.3.5.tar.gz

[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ split -b 100K opendocman-1.3.5.tar.gz 
[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ ls
opendocman-1.3.5.tar.gz  xaa  xab  xac  xad  xae  xaf  xag  xah  xai  xaj  xak  xal  xam  xan  xao  xap  xaq  xar  xas  xat  xau
[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ ll
total 4072
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py 2082602 Jan  5 11:06 opendocman-1.3.5.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xaa
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xab
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xac
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xad
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xae
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xaf
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xag
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xah
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xai
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xaj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xak
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xal
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xam
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xan
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xao
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xap
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xaq
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xas
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py  102400 Jan  5 11:06 xat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py   34602 Jan  5 11:06 xau
[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ cat xa* > opendoc-reassembled.tar.gz
[kent_x86.py@c7 split-test]$ ls -l opendoc-reassembled*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kent_x86.py kent_x86.py 2082602 Jan  5 11:07 opendoc-reassembled.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` command.

```
split -C 1G <filename>
```

For more details take a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016894/how-to-split-a-large-text-file-into-smaller-files-with-equal-number-of-lines)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used `sed` to extract an arbitrary number of lines:

```
sed -n 1,1000000p infile.xml>outfile.xml
```

Comment: Putting aside whether this answers the question or not, this will scan the entire file, I believe, so it's much more efficient to use `sed 1000000q` (and a bit more compact, visually speaking).